# Specify some but not all type parameters when calling a generic function?

Tags: generics, scala-3

I want to specify the first type parameter of a generic function call but not the second:

```scala
def stupid[A, B](a: A, b: B): Unit = ()

stupid[Int, _](23, "Hi") // specifically set A but want the compiler to infer B=String
```

**UPDTE**: I know in Scala 2 this is not possible out of the box. Perhaps there is a theoretical reason behind it (would appreciate it if someone clarifies as to why). I'm specifically asking for Scala 3 though.

Comment: I think there are some proposals to do this in different ways, but I don't know if you can do this currently :(

Comment: @user Care to post the link to the SIP ?

Comment: there is this https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/named-typeargs-spec.html

Comment: higher rank types to the rescue can work in a limited fashion https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html